# Allow contents of array in eq comparison to be anything in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, graphql

I have a GraphQL API using Ruby (on Rails) and have come across a situation when writing request tests that to maintain high readability should accept an array to have any content in an `eq` comparison.

Like this:

```
         expect(json_response).to eq({
            data: {
              Post: {
                PostId: nil,
                wasUpdated: false,
                errors[<Any error acceptet here>]
              }
            }
          })
```

I tried with: 
`errors[*]`
... didn't work.

Let me walk you through it. It is a general test to see that the PostId: nil and the wasUpdated: false AND the error array is returned when some error occurs. As this is a general fail test it is of no interest to specify what specific error is returned.

**Hence my question; how do I write to allow for all the above being expected BUT in the error-array anything goes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RSpec composition to help with this [Docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-8/docs/composing-matchers)

In this case your test would look like:

```
expect(json_response).to match({
        data: {
          Post: {
            PostId: nil,
            wasUpdated: false,
            errors: an_instance_of(Array)
          }
        }
      })
```

[Working Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/RSpecCompositionMatcher)